# SAPUI5 How to trigger a dialog box while I mouse over an appointment on the PlanningCalendar entity

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover, sapui5

I am using the PlanningCalendar entity present in [SAPUI5 Explored](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html). I want to show some kind of box with information (type, startDate, endDate) about a certain appointment while I mouse over it. This entity has no event for a mouse over, so is there a way to create it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea: all appointments are rendered inside sap.ui.unified.CalendarRow control, and one of the problem is that depending on the view several appointments can be merged into a single visible appointment, so a possible solution could be redefining on the fly sap.ui.unified.CalendarRow.protptype.onmouseover event, and it should be based on the code of CalendarRow.prototype.onsapselect.